# oracle sql question98

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to display the date most recent order as well as the order id associated with that order but I can't seem to figure out how to only return the unique order id for that that most recent order.
Here's what I have so far:

```
select  custlastname || ', ' || custfirstname as Contact_Name,
max(orderdate), orderid
from customer inner join custorder
on customer.customerid = custorder.customerid
where state = 'OH' and companyname is not null  
group by custlastname, custfirstname, orderid
order by custlastname, custfirstname;
```

This returns 10 results, but I only want the most recent order with that specific order ID?

Comment: Please abstain from massively editing your question (deleting relevant information) after it has been answered. Doing so is very confusing if someone visits your question later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select  custlastname || ', ' || custfirstname as Contact_Name, orderid
from customer c inner join
     (select o.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by orderdate desc) as seqnum
      from custorder o
     ) o
     on c.customerid = o.customerid and seqnum = 1
where state = 'OH' and companyname is not null  ;
order by custlastname, custfirstname;
```

Comment: I've never used that before/ learned that in class yet.  Is there another possible way?

Comment: Lots of ways, but this is probably the best.

Comment: what would be another way that say someone who's just started learning sql might be able to better relate to?